# Vinkla instagram in Laravel 5.3 Showing Error

Tags: php, laravel-5, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to integrate vinkla/instagram v6.0 in Laravel 5.3. But it is showing error. I tried the following steps...

1. Run `composer require vinkla/instagram` command in my application root.
   It worked properly.
2. Added the service provider to `config/app.php` in the providers array:
   `Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider::class`

   and in aliases `'Instagram' => Vinkla\Instagram\Facades\Instagram::class`
3. When I run the `php artisan vendor:publish` command it shows the following error:

   [image: Error Image]

How can I solve it? Please help...

Comment: once do, composer update. And check

Comment: I have already done it but composer update also showing this error.

Comment: what error you are facing after composer update

Comment: This is the error...[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem resembles mine,

Try running,

`php artisan config:clear` And `php artisan cache:clear`

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: When I run those commands it is also showing the same error.
F:\laragon\www\api_instagram>php artisan config:clear


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider' not found

Comment: try running composer dump-autoload and then above two commands

Comment: composer dump-autoload is working but still the above two commands are not working.

Comment: restart terminal and then all three commands and check, if not, again start from step 1

Comment: I am starting from step 1

Comment: I have tried from the step 1 but still the problem remaining

Comment: Ok, let me go through again for sample

Comment: Ok, it will be a pleasure to me, if the problem is solved

Comment: Don't do anything, just use it in controller like 

*use Vinkla\Instagram\Instagram;* and $instagram = new Instagram();
$instagram->get('jerryseinfeld');
and check.

Comment: here is working fine and yes remove entries from app.php too. just use it

Comment: welcome !!! If our conversation solves your problem, you can upvote it and accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: I am very sorry to say that I haven't enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: Thanks ! Welcome to StackOverflow Mate !!